# Unable to delete a UITableView row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I try to delete a table view row, the code below deletes the wrong row or deletes all of them at once.

Here's my code:

```
self.books.remove(at: sender.indexPath!.row) 
self.tableView.beginUpdates(); 
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [sender.indexPath!], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic) self.tableView.endUpdates();
```

Comment: you probably deleting data but not different row.

Comment: Why are you removing two items from the array?